# I need to erase warning light

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha

Does my 2019 Yamaha smax xc155kr have an obd2 port or is there another way to attach a reader? Locations, please.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are you just trying to clear a code? If so, have you tried unplugging the battery for a period of time? (Usually 30 minutes will ensure the ECU is blanked on most vehicles.)

Comment: Have you checked the Owner's manual? That will likely tell you the location. Or looked under the seat? Or contacted the dealer?

Comment: For any of these sorts of questions your best bet is to put "vehicle type obd2 location" into google, and not only do you get back text answers, but also video showing the port. Please always use the manual or google for simple things like this

Comment: Many motorcycles do have a port but most don't have a standard OBD2 implementation.  Generally you need a Yamaha-specific tool which means you will need to go to the dealer.  You might check some of the Yamaha Forums and see if anyone there know how to do this.

Comment: Will it go out if you fix whatever is being warned?

Comment: I  have searched google, the manual, wiring diagram youtube, Yamaha forums and went to two dealerships. I have received no answers on the diagnostic port location on the Smax, One of the dealers said it would seem Yamaha doesn't want you to know.

Answer (score 0):

the newer models should have the ability to connect a code reader to a port within the front cowl. You may need a 3pin to OBD adapter cable to do it though.